# WP Job Manager get job listing?

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress / PHP skills arn't as good as I would like yet but hoping someone can help me.

I have a program that I would like to check some job details but I just can't seem to work out how to load a job into say `$post` by it's `JobID`.

I have tried doing something like the following however it just doesn't work, I understand this is more than likely wrong but I can't work out how to do it:

```
  $jobid = 2691
  $post = get_job_listing($jobid);
  if (is_position_filled()) {
    echo 'Do Something';
  } else {
    echo 'Do something else';
  }
```

Comment: Two things: 1) what does `var_dump($post);` display?; 2) according to the documentation, [is_position_filled()](https://wpjobmanager.com/document/template-tags/#section-2) expects to receive a `$post` object or it'll default to `null` and try to use the `$post` object of the current page, so if you want to check if a specific position is available I'm guessing you can also pass the function its ID directly (eg. `is_position_filled($jobid)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @cabrerahector is almost correct, but I believe you should use `$post` not `$jobid` as the parameter to `is_position_filled()`.

```
$jobid = 2691
$post = get_job_listing($jobid);
if (is_position_filled($post)) {
  echo 'Do Something';
} else {
  echo 'Do something else';
}
```

Comment: this does seem logical however I think my problem here is that the function get_job_listing doesn't seem to exist, get_job_listings does however that's more of a search function. 

I guess what i'm trying to ask is how can I retrieve a post with the jobid = $jobid? 

It's probably something simple like $post = get_post($postid->$jobid) or something, but like I said my WordPress/PHP skills are lacking :)

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  Sorry, assumed the function get_job_listing existed.

Comment: ok, I was close - have it working now with $post = get_post($jobid) so simple!! thanks guys